# How do I use command-line arguments to `sh` in the `-c` command string?

Tags: command-line, bash, sh, dash-shell

I know that

```
sh -c 'echo $1' sh 4
```

will output `4`.
and

```
sh -c 'echo $2' sh 4 5
```

will output `5`.

But I cannot understand how the parameters after the second `sh` were passed to the command next to `sh -c`. I read the man page of both `bash` and `dash` but could not find the introduction about this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is actually specified by [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#), which all Bourne-like shells should support to claim themselves portable.

> sh -c [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
>         command_string [command_name [argument...]]

See the `command_string` parameter ? Now let's look at `-c` flag description:

> -c
>
> Read commands from the command_string operand. **Set the value of special parameter 0 (see Special Parameters) from the value of the command_name operand** and the positional parameters ($1, $2, and so on) in sequence from the remaining argument operands. No commands shall be read from the standard input.

In other words, where in normal shell script `$0` (which is usually shell name in interactive mode or script name when you run a script) would be set by the shell itself, with `-c` you have to specify it yourself. Thus,

```
sh -c 'echo Hi, I am $0 , my first positional parameter is $1' foobar 5
```

would set the process name to `sh` foobar.

Just in case you're wondering what `$0` is, it's also covered in "Special Parameters" section of [Shell Command Language Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> 0
>
> (Zero.) Expands to the name of the shell or shell script.

Answer (score 4):

From `man sh`:

```
-c string If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from
          string.  If there are arguments after the string,  they  are
          assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

In your command the second `sh` is just a parameter with position `0` while `4` has position `1` and so on.

You can run this to check:

```
$ sh -c 'echo $0' sh 4 5
sh
```

Comment: That seems to be the text in Bash's man page. It's actually incorrect in that it implies that `$0` is one of the positional parameters. It isn't. The [POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html) states that "A positional parameter is a parameter denoted by the decimal value represented by one or more digits, *other than the single digit 0*.", and [Bash's manual itself](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters) contains that same definition.